# How to use a javascript function from an external script in lightning controller?

Tags: controller

I want to load a function from external script and then use it in the component controller:

example of a function that i tried to call from the component controller (from the Init method specifically)

```
 function myFunction() {
    log.console('Hiiii'); 
}
```

I loaded the script like that:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.DataArrays}"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" />
```

then i tried simply to call it from the Init method:

```
    doInit : function(cmp){

  myFunction();
}
```

It does not work, i got an error like this one:

```
Uncaught Action failed: c:realEstateFilterComponent$controller$doInit [myFunction is not defined]
```

Do you know to make it work ?

Comment: Did you try `window.myFunction();` inside the doInit method?

Comment: Yes i used Window.myFunction, when i specify another function than DoInit() in  afterScriptsLoaded , it works.

Comment: but inside the doInit i get the undefined error.

Comment: In your resource file do like this : `window.myFunction = function (){..}` then try as mentioned in my first comment..it will work. I just tried on my end.

Comment: i tried that, you can refer to this page http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136760/static-resource-in-lighting-component,  i used as a reference, the resource file have already window attached to it, but still does not work for me, i decided not to use doInit and replace it with onther afterScriptsLoaded function.

Comment: It is the same concept.. Whatever functions we want to invoke that are present inside the static resource need to be attached to window object to be able to call them from lightning controller functions.

Comment: Yes, maybe the doInit() function get executed before afterScriptsLoaded function (before the JavaScript file) ), i think that why i get the undefined error. i may be wrong, but it's the only explanation i can think of.

Comment: May be you have line like this in your component? `<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />` If yes, then resource is not loaded by then.

Comment: Exactly, i deleted this line and it worked.