# Unable to use 'use strict' JS library in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura

To implement a smart Lazy loading mechanism in my custom grid I want to use the [Appear JS library](https://github.com/creativelive/appear). From reading the specs it seems to be usable as it has use strict mode.

**appear.js**

```
appear = (function(){
  'use strict';
  var scrollLastPos = null, scrollTimer = 0, scroll = {};

  function track(){
    var newPos = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;  // pageYOffset for IE9
```

I store this js inside a static resource, embed it in

**myComponent.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.NAMESPACE__appear_js}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.initAppearLib}" />
```

and initialize it [as described here](https://github.com/creativelive/appear/blob/master/README.md) in a loader method in

**myComponentController.js**

```
({
    initAppearLib: function(cmp, evt, hlp) {
        appear({
            init: function init(){
                console.log('dom is ready');
            },
            elements: function elements(){
                // work with all elements with the class "track"
                return document.getElementsByClassName('track');
            },
            appear: function appear(el){
                console.log('visible', el);
            },
            disappear: function disappear(el){
                console.log('no longer visible', el);
            },
            bounds: 200,
            reappear: true
        });
    },
});
```

But...it fails during loading the lib with. It seems not able to load the lib correctly

> [appear is not defined]
>   Object.eval()@https://cprm-pm-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1521850000000/UP2GO_CPRM_BM__appear_js:14:8
>   Object.eval()@https://cprm-pm-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1521850000000/UP2GO_CPRM_BM__appear_js:261:4
>   eval()@https://cprm-pm-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1521850000000/UP2GO_CPRM_BM__appear_js:264:12

Maybe because Locker service is wrapping the appear code inside such a Proxy object?!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign this to **global scope** which is `window`;

So go with `window.appear = (function(){});` instead of `appear = (function(){});` and when you want to use this use with `window` so:

```
({
  initAppearLib: function (cmp, evt, hlp) {
    window.appear({
      init: function init () {
        console.log('dom is ready');
      },
      elements: function elements () {
        // work with all elements with the class "track"
        return document.getElementsByClassName('track');
      },
      appear: function appear (el) {
        console.log('visible', el);
      },
      disappear: function disappear (el) {
        console.log('no longer visible', el);
      },
      bounds: 200,
      reappear: true
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: The problem even occurs before this code is executed. So this solution alone doesn't work.  From the answer below I learned that I also have to modify the lib code as well and add a window. to the appear. But even then. Same error. Did you try it on you own org?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the same with a community and I am not getting any error. Here is the URL: [Appear.js with lightning](https://itzruns-developer-edition.ap5.force.com/s/appearjs)

Comment: Cool. Would you mind sharing the source code?

Comment: You have access to all of it already. Just open the network tab and save the static resource content and the component's controller JS content. :P

Comment: from this community page [Appear.js with lightning](https://itzruns-developer-edition.ap5.force.com/s/appearjs) you can see the code.

Comment: I see the static resource. Am I right that you took the normal appear.js and just added window. at a single spot? I don't see you controller code. I need to know its name to find it in the Source tab. Or you could add it to you answer.

Comment: Yes, just added `window.` at a single place, rest is same and the controller code is already in the answer; ;)

Comment: Then I don't get why it doesn't work for me?

Comment: Still not working?

Comment: No now it's telling me that window.appear doesn't exist

Comment: Can you please share it in the form of lightning community public page where I can have a look?

Comment: No I got it. I was using the wrong appear.js. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen this post [How to use a javascript function from an external script in lightning controller?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163137/how-to-use-a-javascript-function-from-an-external-script-in-lightning-controller)

Based on the directions from the above post, tried below and the error message did not show:

i believe you are also including jquery resource before appear.js?

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.NAMESPACE_yourjqueryresource}" />

/* appearlazy.js 1.0.3 */
window.appear = function() {
  'use strict';
  var nodes = [];

  function addClass(el) {
    if (el.classList) {
      el.classList.add('appeared');
    } else {
      // IE9 compat
      el.className += ' ' + 'appeared';
    }
  }

  // set the image src or background attribute
  function doReveal(el) {
    var orig = el.getAttribute('src') || false;

    el.addEventListener('error', function handler(e) {
      // on error put back the original image if available (usually a placeholder)

      if (orig) {
        el.setAttribute('src', orig);
      }
      el.removeEventListener('error', handler); // hate this.
    });

    var src = el.getAttribute('data-src');
    if (src) {
      el.setAttribute('src', src);
      addClass(el);
      return;
    }
    src = el.getAttribute('data-bkg');
    if (src) {
      el.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + src + '")';
      addClass(el);
      return;
    }
  }

  // find what element to work with, as we support containers of images
  function reveal(el) {
    if (el.hasChildNodes()) {
      // dealing with a container try and find children
      var els = el.querySelectorAll('[data-src], [data-bkg]');
      var elsl = els.length;
      if (elsl === 0) {
        // node has children, but none have the attributes, so reveal
        // the node itself (use case: div with a background)
        doReveal(el);
      } else {
        for (var j = 0; j < elsl; j++) {
          doReveal(els[j]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      doReveal(el);
    }
  }

  // reveal an image after a specified timeout
  function delayAppear(el, delay) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      reveal(el);
    }, delay);
  }

  return {
    // function executed when dom is interactive
    init: function init() {
      // find all elements with the class "appear"
      var els = document.getElementsByClassName('appear');
      var elsl = els.length;
      //  put html elements into an array object to work with
      for (var i = 0; i < elsl; i += 1) {
        // some images are revealed on a simple timeout, instead of
        // viewport appears. These delays appears must have
        // the appear class on them directly
        var delay = els[i].getAttribute('data-delay');
        if (delay) {
          delayAppear(els[i], delay);
        } else {
          nodes.push(els[i]);
        }
      }
    },
    elements: nodes,
    // function to run when an element is determined to be in view
    appear: reveal,
    // larger bounds area for reveal images
    bounds: 200
  };

}();
```

Hope it works for you!!

Comment: I don't get your answer. Why are you talking about jquery. I don't need it and don't have it. I also don't get your source example. Looks like you are putting the init code directly into the cmp file. How should that work?

Comment: Please do not put init code inside the component, sorry if that was unclear. I meant you have to modify the `appearlazy.js` and re-upload to the same static resource that you used in`<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.NAMESPACE__appear_js}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.initAppearLib}" />`. Hope that helps!!

Comment: And why? What is the difference with the lazy version?

Comment: So i did this:
**Step-1**: Under `Download` section of the git repo you provided, i downloaded [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creativelive/appear/master/dist/appear.js] which I think the js file in [http://creativelive.github.io/appear/examples/lazy/] had the `appearlazy.js` comment on top.
***appearlazy uses appear.js to lazy load images or divs that have an "appear" class. It works by switching a data-src attribute into the src as an image is identified as viewable.*** 
**Step-2**: Modified the `appear.js` file mentioned above.
hope it helps..