# Function from Javscript Static Resource coming as Undefined after enabling Locker Service

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, locker-service

After enabling Locker service, javascript function from static resource is coming as undefined.

---

JS file:

```
function myFunc(){
   return '1';
}
```

Lightning component:

```
    <aura:component controller="AccController" implements="force:appHostable" access="global">
        <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.AccLexJS}"
          afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.controllerFunction}" />  
    </aura:component>
```

Lightning Controller:

```
({
    controllerFunction : function(component, event, helper) {

        var action = component.get("c.getInitialVals");

        action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
           var JSreturnVal = myFunc();
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }

})
```

This results in following error:

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in $A.getCallback() [myFunc is not defined].
I am defining or calling the method wrong? 
If I copy paste the JS function in controllerFunction itself then it works with LockerService enabled.

Comment: I found the answer from a related post. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136760/static-resource-in-lighting-component

Comment: I think you need to attach it to the `SecureWindow`